# Problem shifting values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects.  Each Object contains two values, `x` and `y`.  I want to move the objects up, so after processing `object[0]`, `object[0]` takes the value of `object[1]`, `object[1]` takes the value of `object[2]`, etc.

What I find, is when I amend an element of `object[0]`, `object[1]` also changes, so after executing the code below, I'm getting `parts[0] = (40, 20)`, `parts[1] = (40, 20)`, and `parts[2] = (20, 20)`

```
function Part(x, y) {
    this.x = 30;
    this.y = 20;
}

var parts = [];
parts[0] = new Part(30, 20);
parts[1] = new Part(30, 20);
parts[2] = new Part(30, 20);

parts[1].x -= 10;
parts[2].x -= 20;

// so far so good I get an array parts = [(30,20), (20,20), (10, 20)]

// update parts
for (i = parts.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    parts[i] = parts[i - 1];
}

// parts now = [(30, 20), (30, 20), (20, 20)]

parts[0] += 10; // somehow this is also updating parts[1] so ...

// parts = [(40, 20), (40, 20), (20, 20)]
// expecting parts = [(40, 20), (30, 20), (20, 20)]
```

Comment: `parts[i] = parts[i - 1]` makes `parts[i]` and `parts[i - 1]` refer to the same object. Mutating `parts[0]` will also mutate `parts[1]` because `parts[1]` ***is*** `parts[0]` after the assignment.

Comment: If you change `parts[i] = parts[i - 1]` to `Object.assign( parts[i], parts[i - 1] )` or to `parts[i].x = parts[i - 1].x; parts[i].y = parts[i - 1].y;` it will work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you @Paulpro.  I've implemented this suggestion, which has also been suggested by Moritz Roessler and it has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're copying the reference of the object in the line `parts[i] = parts[i - 1]`. If you run `parts [0] === parts [1]` it returns `true`.

A simple workaround would be using `Object.assign`.

```
function Part(x, y) {
  this.x = 30;
  this.y = 20;
}

var parts = [];
parts[0] = new Part(30, 20);
parts[1] = new Part(30, 20);
parts[2] = new Part(30, 20);

parts[1].x -= 10;
parts[2].x -= 20;

// so far so good I get an array parts = [(30,20), (20,20), (10, 20)]

// update parts
for (i = parts.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    parts[i] = Object.assign(new Part, parts[i - 1])
}

// parts now = [(30, 20), (30, 20), (20, 20)]

parts[0].x += 10; // somehow this is also updating parts[1] so 

console.log (parts)
```